# How do I count the number of occurrences of a string in an entire file?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell, unix

Is there an inbuilt command to do this or has anyone had any luck with a script that does it?

I am looking to count the number of times a certain string (not word) appears in a file. This can include multiple occurrences per line so the count should count every occurrence not just count 1 for lines that have the string 2 or more times.

For example, with this sample file:

```
blah(*)wasp( *)jkdjs(*)kdfks(l*)ffks(dl
flksj(*)gjkd(*
)jfhk(*)fj (*) ks)(*gfjk(*)
```

If I am looking to count the occurrences of the string `(*)` I would expect the count to be 6, i.e. 2 from the first line, 1 from the second line and 3 from the third line. Note how the one across lines 2-3 does not count because there is a LF character separating them.

**Update**: great responses so far! Can I ask that the script handle the conversion of `(*)` to `\(*\)`, etc? That way I could just pass any desired string as an input parameter without worrying about what conversion needs to be done to it so it appears in the correct format.

Comment: I don't quite understand your "Update".  Are you looking for Perl's `quotemeta` function, or `\Q` and `\E` within the regex?

Comment: @DavidO - I'm not sure if quotemeta will do the trick. Basically i envision: var_input = "(*)"; var_proper_format = some_func(var_input); while /var_proper_format/g; ....ie so var_proper_format is automatically computed from the given input var_input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using perl's "Eskimo kiss" operator with the `-n` switch to print a total at the end. Use `\Q...\E` to ignore any meta characters.

```
perl -lnwe '$a+=()=/\Q(*)/g; }{ print $a;' file.txt
```

Script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count;
my $text = shift;

while (<>) {
    $count += () = /\Q$text/g;
}

print "$count\n";
```

Usage:

```
perl script.pl "(*)" file.txt
```

Comment: How would this be made into a script that accepts an argument?

Comment: I had to use this for a multi-gigabyte XML file, without line breaks. grep+wc didn't work so well, but this solution ran lightning fast and worked great! Go Perl!

Answer (score 23):

You can use basic tools such as `grep` and `wc`:

```
grep -o '(\*)' input.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: How would this be made into a script that accepts an argument?

Comment: +1 Or even a verifiable `echo $'blah(*)wasp( *)jkdjs(*)kdfks(l*)ffks(dl\nflksj(*)gjkd(*\n)jfhk(*)fj (*) ks)(*gfjk(*)' | grep -o '(\*)' | wc -l`.

Answer (score 2):

This loops over the lines of the file, and on each line finds all occurrences of the string "(*)".  Each time that string is found, $c is incremented.  When there are no more lines to loop over, the value of $c is printed.

`perl -ne'$c++ while /\(\*\)/g;END{print"$c\n"}' filename.txt`

**Update:** Regarding your comment asking that this be converted into a solution that accepts a regex as an argument, you might do it like this:

`perl -ne'BEGIN{$re=shift;}$c++ while /\Q$re/g;END{print"$c\n"}' 'regex' filename.txt`

That ought to do the trick.  If I felt inclined to skim through [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) again I might see a more elegant solution, but this should work.

You could also eliminate the explicit inner while loop in favor of an implicit one by providing list context to the regexp:

`perl -ne'BEGIN{$re=shift}$c+=()=/\Q$re/g;END{print"$c\n"}' 'regex' filename.txt`

Comment: How would this be made into a script that accepts an argument?

Comment: @toop See my update for a solution that allows you to specify the regex on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic **grep** command:

**Example**: If you want to find the no of occurrence of  "hello" word in a file

```
grep -c "hello" filename
```

If you want to find the no of occurrence of a pattern then

```
grep -c -P "Your Pattern"
```

Pattern example : **hell.w, \d+**  etc

Answer (score 0):

I have used below command to find particular string count in a file

grep search_String fileName|wc -l

Comment: The questions asks for a perl solution, and the anser by Arjit already gives the "perfect" way of solving this with grep -c. In that sense: your answer doesn't really add anything helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

```
text="(\*)"
grep -o $text file | wc -l
```

You can make it into a script which accepts arguments like this:

script **count**:

```
#!/bin/bash
text="$1"
file="$2"
grep -o "$text" "$file" | wc -l
```

Usage:

```
./count "(\*)" file_path
```

Comment: ... That is the same of most voted answer. Are you trying to re-post all bash answer?

Comment: someone wanted to make a script out of this, I was working on that

Comment: Comment or edit the answer by add your contribution... file a new answer is just noise.

Comment: editing someones answer to add mine doesn't seem fair. And commenting codes isn't that efficient.